# Adding a column to a table in MySQL database with default value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, utc, datetime-conversion

I have a table named tab1. I want add a new column to the table.
I tried

```
alter table tab1 add column mod_at TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I succeeded in adding the column. But the default timestamp value added will be local timestamp. How to add the UTC timestamp as default value, instead of local timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you misunderstand how `TIMESTAMP` column type works. This column always uses UTC internally, but it converts from/to server/session time zone when you read or write. You can run this query to see your session's time zone:

```
SELECT @@session.time_zone
```

Now, if you change the time zone, e.g.:

```
SET @@session.time_zone = '+00:00'
```

... you'll see that the values already stored change to match the new time zone. That's the expected behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

you could use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` instead

Comment: Using `alter table tab1 add column mod_at TIMESTAMP default UTC_TIMESTAMP()` or `ALTER TABLE a ADD COLUMN mod_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT UTC_TIMESTAMP` is not possible you will get a error

Comment: Not Possible @Raymond